# Light saturated color scheme for Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, color-scheme, sublimetext3

Advise me, please, the good light color scheme for Sublime.
I need saturated theme, like Monokai, but with light background.

Very thanks.

Comment: Currently I use Dawn, but it is not enough saturated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't know what exactly do you want, but **[here](http://devthemez.com/themes/sublime-text-2) [are](http://colorsublime.com/)** 3 **[resources](https://sublime.wbond.net/search/scheme)** to help you out finding what you want.

Remember you can always tweak any scheme to your liking using sublime itself. For example you could modify the Monakai theme.

Here is something that I found by typing in "sublime monokai bright" the secret project called "google"

- [Monokai Light Bright Custom](https://github.com/facelessuser/sublime-settings/blob/master/Color%20Scheme/Monokai%20Light%20Bright%20Custom.tmTheme)
- [Monokai Light theme](https://github.com/victorstanciu/sublime-colors/blob/master/Monokai%20Light.tmTheme)

Remember that SO is not the place to ask opinion based questions or advisements.